# Is this lambda abstraction created as a generator of a recursive function?

Tags: lambda-calculus, recursion

In lambda calculus, a recursive function $f$ is obtained by

$$ f = Y g $$

where $Y$ is the Y combinator and $g$ is the generator of $f$ i.e. $f$ is a fixed point of $g$ i.e.  $f == g f$.

In *The Scheme Programming Language*, I saw an example implementing a recursive function $f$ that sums the integers in a list:

```
(let ([sum (lambda (f ls)
                  (if (null? ls)
                     0
                     (+ (car ls) (f f (cdr ls)))))])
(sum sum '(1 2 3 4 5)))  => 15
```

What is the mathematical derivation that drives to create the lambda abstraction

```
 lambda (f ls)
     (if (null? ls)
         0
        (+ (car ls) (f f (cdr ls))))
```

?
It looks like a generator of $f$, but not entirely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the $Z$ combinator (because we're in an eager context), you have $$Z=\lambda g.(\lambda f.g(\lambda v.ffv))(\lambda f.g(\lambda v.ffv))$$

If you look at the code, we don't apply a fixed point combinator to `sum`, we simply apply `sum` to itself, so there's no reason for `sum` to be "generator".

You can also readily show that `sum` is (modulo currying) equal to $\lambda f.g(\lambda v.ffv)$ for some $g$, basically by replacing `(f f ...)` with `(h ...)` where `h` is the argument to $g$ in the definition for `sum` (minus the outermost `lambda`).

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out at the same time also by looking up the definition of the Y combinator (not sure whether it is called Y or Z). Before seeing the example in the book, I had never met a recursive function computed in such a "convoluted" yet "systematic" way. When is the technique in the example useful?